# Show element if user starts typing

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show an element when the following criteria has been met:
1. The input is in focus
2. The input has 1 or more characters.

My jquery code so far (which doesn't work) is this...

```js
$('input').click(function() {
  if (($(this).is(':focus')) && ($(this).val().length > 1)) {
    $(this).siblings('.show').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  line-height: 22px;
}

main {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 16px;
}

.group {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

label {
  color: #393939;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input,
textarea {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #5c5c5c;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

input:not(textarea) {
  height: 48px;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(74, 168, 81, 1);
}

::placeholder {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #bbb;
}

.hint {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #727272;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

input:focus+.hint {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.show {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <div class="group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="e.g. jamesgreen@gmail.com">
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password">
    <p class="hint">Password must have at least 8 characters, a lower case letter, an uppercase letter and a number</p>
    <span class="show">SHOW</span>
  </div>
</main>
```

Not sure where I am going wrong, here is a link to the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRoPXe)

Comment: try with .on('change') or .on('keyup')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `input` event instead of `click` event and `focus` selector:

```js
$('input').on('input', function(){
    if ($(this).val().length > 1) {
  $(this).siblings('.show').fadeIn();
 } else {
          $(this).siblings('.show').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #5c5c5c;
 line-height: 22px;
}

main {
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 padding: 16px;
}

.group {
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 position: relative;
}

label {
 color: #393939;
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

input,
textarea {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #5c5c5c;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 outline: none; 
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

input:not(textarea){
 height: 48px;
}

input:focus,
textarea:focus {
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(74, 168, 81, 1);
}

::placeholder {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 color: #bbb;
}

.hint {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #727272;
 position: relative;
 top: -5px;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

input:focus + .hint {
 opacity: 1;
 top: 0;
}

.show {
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
    top: 44px;
    right: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="group">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
     <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="e.g. jamesgreen@gmail.com">
 </div>

 <div class="group">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" id="password">
     <p class="hint">Password must have at least 8 characters, a lower case letter, an uppercase letter and a number</p>
     <span class="show">SHOW</span>
 </div>
</main>
```